# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when trying to plot in Notebook

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

Here's my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

nsim = 1000 # aantal simulaties
n = 5 # Aantal deuren


def simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n):
    return np.random.randint(n, size=nsim)

prizedoors = simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n)
print "simulate_prizedoor(nsim = 1000, n = 30)=", prizedoors[:15]


def simulate_guess(nsim, n):
    return np.random.randint(n, size=nsim)

guesses = simulate_guess(nsim, n)
print "simulate_guess(nsim = 1000, n = 30)=", guesses[:15]


def simulate_switch(prizedoor, guess, n):
    switched_list = []
    for sim in range(prizedoor.shape[0]):
        while True:
            randomInt = np.random.randint(n)
            if randomInt != prizedoor[sim] and randomInt != guess[sim]:
                switched_list.append(randomInt)
                break
    return np.array(switched_list)



print "simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(nsim = 10, n), simulate_guess(10, n), n) =", simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(10, n), simulate_guess(10, n), n)


def win_percentage(guesses, prizedoors):
    win = float(0)
    for sim in range(len(guesses)):
        if guesses[sim] == prizedoors[sim]:
            win += 1
    win_perc = (win / len(guesses)) * 100
    return win_perc

print "win_percentage(simulate_guess(nsim, n), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,n))=", win_percentage(simulate_guess(nsim, n), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,n))
print "win_percentage(simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n), simulate_guess(nsim, n), n), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,n))=", win_percentage(simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n), simulate_guess(nsim, n), n), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,n))


print "*** PLOT Intepr 1 ***"

x = np.linspace(0, 20)
y = win_percentage(simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(nsim, x), simulate_guess(nsim, x), x), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,x))

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel("X axis")
plt.ylabel("Y axis")
```

This is the output and the error:

```
simulate_prizedoor(nsim = 1000, n = 30)= [2 1 0 4 3 2 2 2 0 3 1 0 4 1 0]
simulate_guess(nsim = 1000, n = 30)= [2 0 1 3 1 3 1 4 3 2 0 0 3 4 2]
simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(nsim = 10, n), simulate_guess(10, n), n) = [2 3 0 3 4 2 1 3 1 1]
win_percentage(simulate_guess(nsim, n), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,n))= 18.9
win_percentage(simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n), simulate_guess(nsim, n), n), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,n))= 21.4
*** PLOT Intepr 1 ***
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-55303947fa57> in <module>()
     53 
     54 x = np.linspace(0, 20)
---> 55 y = win_percentage(simulate_switch(simulate_prizedoor(nsim, x), simulate_guess(nsim, x), x), simulate_prizedoor(nsim,x))
     56 
     57 plt.plot(x, y)

<ipython-input-1-55303947fa57> in simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n)
     10 
     11 def simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n):
---> 12     return np.random.randint(n, size=nsim)
     13 
     14 prizedoors = simulate_prizedoor(nsim, n)

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:9533)()

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I've tried to find a solution and I've rewritten most of the code. First I thought it was because im not using the NP random.randint to determine a random integer. I implemented that but the issue is still the same. Anyone here shed some light on what's exactly going wrong here?

Im trying to plot a graph in matplotlib. With on the y-axis the winpercentage and on the horintal: n.

Feedback appriciated!

Comment: Is there any way you could pose your question without superfluous detail in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to pass an array "x = np.linspace(0,20)" to the function np.random.randint( x, size).  You need to pass single integer values to this function.